# How to get see stdout on Travis CI?

Tags: travis-ci

I want to see the table names in a database created via the .travis.yml file.  Locally I just type

```
mysql myapp_test -e 'show tables;'
```

In the .travis.yml file I put

```
- mysql myapp_test -e 'show tables;'
```

but this doesn't show a list of tables on the [Travis Console](https://travis-ci.org/owen-kellie-smith/reservation/jobs/97460657).

How do I get stdout to show up in the Travis console?

Comment: AFAICS, you're invoking it on [Line 748](https://travis-ci.org/owen-kellie-smith/reservation/jobs/97460657#L748), and the output [follows through line 749 to line 812](https://travis-ci.org/owen-kellie-smith/reservation/jobs/97460657#L749-L812). Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks, but I want to see a list of tables in the database i.e. I want to see what the "show tables" command would show on my console.

Comment: Redirect to stderr, 1>&2